# jQuery ajax POST from local file to access a cross domain not working

Tags: ajax, jquery, cross-domain, cors

As the title says, I'm trying to access (POST) using jQuery AJAX call to a web url, `http://host:port/...` or `http://localhost:8080/...` from a local HTML file, `c:\home.html`. I can't get it to work.

I did Google and also saw several questions here but I can't get it to work. I need some help here. Here is what I've tried so far.

1. dataType: jsonp
2. crossDomain: true
3. Setting the header in my response:

```js
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

None of the three browsers are working - IE, FF or Chrome. The request is never reaching the server. Here are some of the errors I'm seeing.

1. No Transport (IE) if not jsonp is used.
2. NS_BINDING_ABORTED / Error loading content (NS_ERROR_DOCUMENT_NOT_CACHED) in FF

This is my code. I would appreciate any help. I'm using `jquery-1.8.2.min.js`.

```
var http_host =  "http://localhost:8080";

function su (pc, p) {
    var suUrl = http_host + "/ps/api/v2/authorize.json";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: suUrl,
        data: {
            phone_cell: pc,
            password: p,
        },
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        success: osu,
        error: oe
    });
    return false;
}

function osu (d) {
    console.log(d);
}

function oe(xhr, ts, et)     {
    alert("ServerError: " + et);
}
```

An example would be a perfect pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose my code got messed up w/ all the different solutions that I was trying. I was finally able to get it to work w/ setting the header (solution that was recommended and worked for others). All that I had to do to get it to work is add the following to my REST service response.

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Update:

I thought I figured this out but I've not. There is more it than just setting the header. Anyways, in my specific situation. I was trying to run my app (html, js) off of the hard drive specifically on chrome and trying to access web services available on the cloud.

Here is how I finally solved the problem. I started the chrome w/ the following parameters.

```
--disable-web-security -–allow-file-access-from-files
```

Like I mentioned earlier, this app is really a desktop application that will be run as part of the chromium embedded framework.

Thanks every one for your input.

Answer (score 3):

You can't make a cross-domain request from a local file because it's not on a **domain**. You need  to host `C:\home.html` on a local webserver instance in order for it to work.

Comment: The solution is part of a desktop application and goes into the CEF (Chromium Embeddd Framework). So I'm first trying to get it to work on Chrome and eventually move it to CEF. The point is I can't have a local web server running.

Comment: @user977505 Well you can't make a cross-domain request then.

Comment: @Jivings Your answer is partially correct, but you forget something important: You **can** do cross-domain requests from local files **if** your request doesn't execute the preflight request. This can be done in many browsers (including chrome and IE8) by obeying two rules:

Request does not set custom HTTP headers like 'application/xml' or 'application/json' etc
The request method has to be one of GET, HEAD or POST. If POST, content type should be one of application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain