# JQuery is loading but my javascript isn't

Tags: javascript, html

So, according to the firefox debugger both index.js and jquery.js are loading fine but the code in index.js is not running.

Here is the JS:

```
 var Text = "JS Says hi";
 var Num1 = 33.6669;
 var Num2 = 322.0258;

 $('#body').ready(function () {
     pageLoad();
 });

 $('#button').click(function () {
     buttonClick();
 });


 function pageLoad() {
     $('#button').css('visibility","visible');
 }
 function buttonClick() {
     $().post('server.php', {Text:Text,Num1:Num1,Num2:Num2});
 }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bullshit</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>

</head>
<body id="body">
    <button id="button" style="visibility:hidden">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$('#body').ready` should be `$(document).ready` 
also `$().post` should be `$.post`

Comment: and `$('#button').css('visibility","visible');` should be `$('#button').css('visibility','visible');`

Comment: First try in the console of firefox if console.log(Text); to verify if text has a value. and change $.post(.....)   to  $.get(....) it is possible that's a problem of CORS

Comment: if you open an HTML file directly on browser like :
file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/index.html , you can't send a POST, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816286/jquery-ajax-post-from-local-file-to-access-a-cross-domain-not-working.

Comment: I sincerely apologize for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors in your code:

- `$('#body')` should be `$(document)`
- `$().post` should be: `$.post`
- `$('#button').css('visibility","visible');` should be `$('#button').css('visibility','visible');`

  ```
  var Text = "JS Says hi";
  var Num1 = 33.6669;
  var Num2 = 322.0258;

  $(document).ready(function () {
      pageLoad();

      $('#button').click(function () {
          buttonClick();
      });
  });

  function pageLoad() {
      $('#button').css('visibility','visible');
  }

  function buttonClick() {
      $.post('server.php', {Text:Text,Num1:Num1,Num2:Num2});
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This section:

```
$('#body').ready(function () {
     pageLoad();
 });
```

Probably works, but the general way to write this is

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... } )
```

or, the shorthand

```
$(function(){ ... });
```

---

This bit

```
$('#button').click(function () {
     buttonClick();
 });
```

Needs to be *inside* the jQuery `ready` function, so that the event handler is only attached when the document is ready.

```
$(function(){
    $('#button').click(function () {
         buttonClick();
     });
})
```

---

You also have mismatched quotes - you can use `"` or `'` in javascript around strings, but the opener must match the closer

```
$('#button').css('visibility","visible');
```

should/could be

```
$('#button').css("visibility","visible");
```

Answer (score -1):

The error is in your jquery visibility declaration. You've started with ' and ended up in " and vice versa. Also in button click listener, use $.post instead of $().post

```
function pageLoad() {
    $('#button').css('visibility','visible');
}

function buttonClick() {
    $.post('server.php', {Text:Text,Num1:Num1,Num2:Num2});
}
```