# unable to get the rest response with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've the below HTML code.

```
<html>    
<head>
    <script>
        function someFunction() {
            var strWindowFeatures = "location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
            var win = window.open(URL, "_blank", strWindowFeatures);
            win.document.write(UserAction());
            win.document.close();
        }

        function UserAction() {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.open("GET", "myUrl", false);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encode("myId:myPwd"));
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            xhttp.send();
            var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="someFunction()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Here when I click on the button it is opening a new window and there it is showing the error as below screenshot.

[image]

when I see the `console.log()` I see the message as below in my new(popup) window.

> Not allowed to load local resource:
>   file:///C:/Users/rakesh.keerthi/Desktop/nodePractice/AlexaNode/function%20URL()%20%7B%20[native%20code]%20%7D

in my actual html page I get the error as

> sample.html:17 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///C:/Users/rakesh.keerthi/Desktop/nodePractice/AlexaNode/myUrl.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https. UserAction @ sample.html:17
>   someFunction @ sample.html:8 onclick @ sample.html:26 sample.html:17
>   Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest':
>   Failed to load
>   'file:///C:/Users/rakesh.keerthi/Desktop/nodePractice/AlexaNode/myUrl'.
>       at UserAction (file:///C:/Users/rakesh.keerthi/Desktop/nodePractice/AlexaNode/sample.html:17:19)
>       at someFunction (file:///C:/Users/rakesh.keerthi/Desktop/nodePractice/AlexaNode/sample.html:8:32)
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick (file:///C:/Users/rakesh.keerthi/Desktop/nodePractice/AlexaNode/sample.html:26:53)

When I try the same thing in postman it works, unable to understand where am I going wrong. please let me know how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: You are attempting to access a local file, this is not allowed as the 2nd error message states.  If you are not expecting to access a local file then something is wrong with your URL.

Comment: xhttp.open("GET", "myUrl", false);

Are you actually using that in your code? Where is the URL you're attempting to open?

Comment: @AlexK. I'm actually making a rest call to an URL in `myUrl`, no where I'm using a local file.

Comment: Well you are: "*cannot load file:///C:/Users/rakesh.keerthi/*" - where else would this error & path come from?  Does the URL you are using have the correct protocol prefix?

Comment: @ASOlivieri, apologies for that, `myUrl` is a restricted one related to my organization, that's why I made it as `myUrl`, the format is like `https://myRestCallAdress.com/restOfTheEndpoint`.

Comment: @AlexK., 1 quick question, might be dumber than dumbest. I'm having this file saved as `sample.html`. Can I run this directly, or, should this be deployed into a server for sure? Apologies for asking such question

Comment: Are you sure that you have added http/https to the URL (myUrl) ?

Comment: It should be on the same domain (so online) otherwise you will have to mess about to get a local Ajax request to work with a remote server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816286/jquery-ajax-post-from-local-file-to-access-a-cross-domain-not-working

Comment: @Aneesv, yes I'm sure that I've added `http`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google chrome you could try running it with the

```
--allow-file-access-from-files
```

> switch enabled

Answer (score 0):

You either have to run this from the same domain which has the resource your AJAX is calling or you have to setup [Cross Domain Ajax](https://snook.ca/archives/javascript/cross_domain_aj).